# Resharper braces

Tags: resharper

In resharper 4.5 for VS2008, is there a way to get a solid straight line to be shown between starting brace and ending braces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add that feature to Visual Studio by installing CodeRush Xpress (it's compatible with ReSharper). Free download is here:

http://www.devexpress.com/crx

That feature is called Structural Highlighting and you can see a [screen shot of it on this page](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/navigation.xml).

Comment: I'm a historical resharper addict, but the coderush UI embellishments are way cooler.  Two thumbs up.

Comment: I'm finally going to check out CodeRush.  I've been meaning to forever.  Also, Mark, two thumbs up on the "Campbell Franklin" decision!

Comment: I tried CodeRush and felt it has too many bells and whistles - too "in my face". IMO, it shows its heritage from a GUI-centric company.

Comment: Cristi - thanks for the feedback. Every visual feature in CodeRush can be adjusted to suit your preferences or disabled, and many of the action hints explaining what happened automatically turn off with repeated feature usage. So over time as you learn, or as you adjust the settings, it tends to settle down into something that can feel like a jet fighter cockpit wrapped around you. We'll be working to improve the balance and feel for new devs in future releases.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper > Options > Editor > Highlight matching delimiters...

Comment: That highlights the brace characters, but it doesn't show a line connecting the pair of braces.  At least not on my machine.

Comment: ReSharper 4.5: Highlight matching delimiters when caret is "at both sides" & Highlight with "outline". It draws "a line" around the entire code block.  I missed the part in the question about the line being "straight", so my answer fails.

Answer (score 0):

In VS2013 this feature is available in the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) add-in.  Once installed it is controled from Tools-Options-Productivity Power Tools-Other Extensions-Structure visualizer options-Show code structure in the editor.